# Are all Semi-Euler Graphs Euler Graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am confused about semi-euler graphs, my discrete mathematics course instructor says semi-euler graphs as not euler graphs, however [This link](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/euler-graph-euler-trail-euler-circuit/) suggests that it may or may not be.

Comment: Eul**e**r, not Eular

Comment: That linked article seems confused. It first correctly says "If a connected graph contains an Euler trail but does not contain an Euler circuit, then such a graph is called as a semi-Euler graph." but in note 03 and note 06 it contradicts that by allowing Euler circuits. While either definition would work, generally semi-Euler graphs exclude Euler circuits so are not Euler graphs.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner My apologies, Please edit it.

Comment: You may find that eulerian graphs are semi-eulerian, but not vice versa